# Sparkjs and Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive

Im trying to create a interface for my Spark.io device using Angularjs. Sparkjs uses

var spark = require('spark');
to load the external javascript.
Im trying to create a directive for this, but it gives me an error when using "require('spark')"

```
.directive('ngSpark', function() {
  return {
        restrict: 'EA',        
        scope: {},

        templateUrl: 'views/.html',      
        link: function (scope, element)
        {
         var spark=require('spark');

          spark.login({username: 'user@email.com', password: 'password'});
          spark.on('login',function(data){
             console.log(data) ;
          });
        }

      };
```

});

From the documentation, "SparkJS is a library for interacting with your cores and the Spark Cloud. It uses node.js and "require" is a way to load a module." http://docs.spark.io/javascript/
And I have loaded the  on index.html
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the middle of making an angular-spark bower that can be consumed and provide some basic interfaces.

You probably figured this out already, but require works differently on the client than it does in node, so the spark object that you are trying to recover won't work. You can include spark using the cdn that is provided on the [Spark Javascript SDK Documentation](http://docs.spark.io/javascript/).

> JS

```
.directive('ngSpark', function() {
  return {
        restrict: 'EA',        
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'views/.html',      
        link: function (scope, element)
        {
          scope.user = {};
          scope.login = function(){
            if(form.$valid) {

              spark.login({
                username: $scope.user.email,
                password: $scope.user.password
              },function(err, body){

                if (!err){
                  $scope.matchError = false;
                  $scope.$dismiss();

                } else {
                  $scope.matchError = true; 
                }


             });
            }
          }
        }

      };
```

> HTML (mine is a ui-bootstrap modal)

```
<form id="spark-login-form" 
      class="spark-login-modal spark-modal current form" 
      style="position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%;  margin-left: -200px; z-index: 2; display: block;"
      ng-submit="login(form)"
      name="form" >
    <div id="spark-login-form-error" class="spark-login-error"></div>
    <input id="spark-login-form-email" type="text" class="spark-login-input" placeholder="email" ng-model="user.email">
    <input id="spark-login-form-password" type="password" name="password" class="spark-login-input" placeholder="password" ng-model="user.password">

    <div class="form-group has-error">
        <p class="help-block" ng-show="form.email.$error.required && form.password.$error.required && submitted">
            Please enter your username and password.
        </p>
    </div>
    <button id="spark-login-form-button" class="spark-login-button" type="submit">
       log in
    </button>
    <a ng-click="$dismiss()" rel="modal:close" class="close-modal ">Close</a>

    <div class="form-group has-error">
        <p class="help-block" ng-show="matchError">
            Oops! It looks like you entered an invalid username or password.
        </p>
    </div>



</form>
```